# How to obfuscate JavaScript which contain some PHP codes?

Tags: javascript, php

Actually, I found a number of tools and websites to obfuscate JavaScript codes, but they didn't work for me. Because my JavaScript codes contain PHP codes.

I wonder if there is a tool or website which supports or handles obfuscation of JavaScript containing PHP codes.

Comment: It would help if you provide sample code.

Comment: Please do read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't really see any reason for including PHP in Javascript. You are doing something VERY wrong somewhere. Besides, obfuscation won't help you in the slightest.

Comment: @Georgi-it: Here is a simple example: var htmlString="<?php echo $htmlString; ?>";
      alert(htmlString);

Answer (score 1):

Putting PHP inside JS is a Bad Idea.

If you need to pass some values to JS from PHP, isolate those values in a separate JS file that only consists of value definitions, so your code is clean and PHP-free.

For example, if you have

```
alert('<?php echo $htmlString; ?>');
```

it is better to separate into

```
// values.js.php
<?php
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
?>
var values = <?php
echo json_encode(Array(
  'htmlString' => $htmlString
));
```

and

```
// code.js
alert(values.htmlString);
```

Then simply make sure you load `values.js.php` before `code.js`. This makes `code.js` a pure JavaScript file, so you can use proper syntax highlighting, tag generation, obfuscation tools, whatever else you want.

(If you are wondering why complicate things with `json_encode`, it is because it makes proper escaping trivial.)

Comment: thanks for comment, then I need a lot of changes in my codes. If there is no **precise answer** to my question, you solution would be a good approach.

Comment: I am pretty sure (not 100% sure, but reasonably sure) there is not. It would be like creating a heat dissipation device that makes sure your dishes don't burn when you cook everything using a flamethrower - a completely unnecessary workaround if you'd just use a stove. :P Separation of concerns is a kind-of pretty important concept in programming, and ignoring it leads to all kinds of problems relating to tooling, debuggability and maintainability (as you're discovering now).